# dask distributed: adding up a collection of vectors residing on different workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a large set of vectors that were computed on different data, thus they reside on different workers. Is the following code the most efficient?

```
grads = [client.submit(compute_grad, x) for x in xs] # list of futures
gradsum_future = client.compute(db.from_sequence(grads).fold(operator.add))
gradsum = client.gather(gradsum_future)
```

Comment: the above code nondeterministically fails with KeyError

Comment: What are the types of the `xs`, and what does `compute_grad` produce? How big are these?

Comment: xs are small python objects that are sent around by pickling. compute_grad produces numpy arrays with 2 million float32s

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I would have implemented it - does that work for you?

```python
grads = client.map(compute_grad, xs)
gradsum_future = client.submit(sum, grads)
gradsum = gradsum _future.result()
```